# What GUI systems let you copy text with formatting preserved, via clipboard?

Tags: operating-systems, software-rec, clipboard, text-formatting, desktop-environments

If you select and copy a text from Internet Explorer and paste it in Miscrosoft Word, the formatting is preserved.

If you do that in Opera or Firefox in Windows, it's lost, IIRC. I use Gnome desktop in Linux, and formatting is preserved nowhere, which is very inconvenient. Even if desktop lets me copy formatted text, I can't post it into any web form: WISYWIG Javascript forms will strip formatting and make me walk through the whole text and fix it manually. I don't know how things are in Macs.

Is there a desktop + browser + editor set that allow passing formatted text consistently throughout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all going to depend on how the source program implements the initial copy to the clipboard and how the target program interprets what's on the clipboard.

IE works because it copies the HTML and Word interprets that HTML.

Chrome copies a certain amount - I've just tried it with a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127314/htaccess-modrewrite-products-phpcat1-to-myfolder1-myproduct1) and I get the heading copied in the correct font as a link and in bold, but the font information is lost on the question body. I'm assuming because that's in the CSS and that isn't copied.

Firefox 3.6 does a worse job - the heading size is preserved but not the font.

IE8 preserves the most in terms of font information.

All preserve the voting arrows, count and favourite star, but the positioning is all wrong.

[image]